# Proof of: There exists a function which dominates all computable ones

Tags: functions, computer-science, turing-machines

Let $C \subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $ be the set of all (turing-)computable functions.

Then:

$$\exists f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}: C \subset o(f)$$

I am looking for a proof and the name of a potential statement implying this statement. Personally, I feel this is very counter-intuitive...

This statement must be true. If you say that a problem $X \in P$, you usually say that $$ \exists M \in  
\mathcal P. \forall x \in X: \text{M accepts x with step counting function f} \in \mathcal{O(px^n)}$$

Now you can proof that such a problem is decidable by defining a Turing machines which halts after it has done at max $f(n)$ steps.

You can now show that this holds true for any function with a computable step counting function.(the complexity class might change, of course)

This is however does not hold true for an uncomputable step counting function $g$.
You could try to contradict, saying that for g there is a bigger $f$, which is computable, such that $g \in \mathcal{O(f(n))}$. But this is known to be false.

Comment: You have good reason to think it's true?

Comment: Wait. I bet it's true for any countable set $\mathcal C$ by a little diagonalization

Comment: $f(n)=n\max_{1\le j\le n}(c_j(n))$.

Comment: When you write $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, did you mean $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It must be true, otherwise you could not show that a problem in NP by some definitions is necessarily decidable. (If you want I can add that in a more explained form)

@JasonDeVito Yes.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This should work, I am 99% convinced.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes. Your argument is very smart. It holds true.  thank you 100% convinced

Comment: The argument is basically that for every computable function enumerated by n, the function will get dominated by f at n and higher

Comment: Adding the bit about NP would be a **very** good idea, what they call "context" in these parts... Also you really should fix the $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ problem.

Comment: Thank you. I tried improving the question accordingly.